# How should I deploy a patch to a Passenger-based production Rails application without downtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a Passenger-based production Rails application which has thousands of users.  Occasionally we need to apply a code patch (we use git) and the current process for doing this (you can assume there are no data migrations) is:

- Perform `git pull origin [production-branch-name]` on the server
- `touch tmp/restart.txt` to restart Passenger

This allows us to patch the server without having to resort to putting up a maintenance page, which is great, but it doesn't feel quite right since it's not actually a proper 'deployment', and we still need to manually update the revision file and our deployment doesn't appear in the Hoptoad or NewRelic services we use.

Ideally I would run `cap production deploy` and just let the standard Capistrano deployment script take care of everything, but is this a dangerous thing to do without putting up a maintenance page?   This deployment process seems to be fairly safe in that the new revision is deployed to a completely separate folder and only right at the end of the process is a symlink re-created to switch the currently deployed version, but I'm still fairly paranoid about this somehow resulting in a lost or failed request.

Answer (score 4):

No problems here doing `cap production deploy`. If the deployment fails then the previous release is still good. Nothing will fail as the old release is loaded (cached) in the current Passenger process. The `touch tmp/restart.txt` will pick up the new release and all is good in the world.